# Fiori assign item to column according to attribute value

Tags: json, xml, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have this Fiori application where I'm filling a table from a JSON file,

My view file:

```
 <mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" controllerName="generated.app.controller.page_1" xmlns:m="sap.m">
    <m:Page showHeader="true" title="Visual SOP 2" showFooter="true" showNavButton="false">

 <m:content>
        <m:Table bindingContexts="complex" id="sap_Responsive_Page_0-content-build_simple_Table-1491380108675" width="100%" mode="None" showSeparators="None" growing="false"
            growingThreshold="20" fixedLayout="true" growingScrollToLoad="false" items="{path:'/DCSet'}">

            <m:columns >
                <m:Column width="auto" hAlign="Center" vAlign="Top" minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true" popinDisplay="Inline" mergeDuplicates="true">
                    <m:header>
                        <m:Text text="Cahier des charges" width="auto" maxLines="1" wrapping="false" textAlign="Begin" textDirection="Inherit"/>
                    </m:header>
                    <m:footer/>
                </m:Column>

                <m:Column width="auto" hAlign="Center" vAlign="Top" minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true" popinDisplay="Inline" mergeDuplicates="true">
                    <m:header>
                        <m:Text text="instruction" width="auto" maxLines="1" wrapping="false" textAlign="Begin" textDirection="Inherit"/>
                    </m:header>
                    <m:footer/>
                </m:Column>
            </m:columns>

            <m:items>
                <m:ColumnListItem  id ="col" type="Inactive">

                                <m:StandardTile title="{label}" number="{ID}" numberUnit="{typeeq}" info="{typedem}" infoState="None" icon="sap-icon://pushpin-off"
                                    press="_onStandardTilePress1"/>

                                <m:StandardTile title="{label}" number="{ID}" numberUnit="{typeeq}" info="{typedem}" infoState="Error" icon="sap-icon://pushpin-off"
                                    press="_onStandardTilePress1"/>


                </m:ColumnListItem>
            </m:items>

        </m:Table>
    </m:content>
    <m:headerContent/>
    <m:subHeader/>
    <m:customHeader/>
</m:Page>
```

My Json file

```
[
{
"ID": "30615",
"label": "Label1",
"col": "col1"
},
{
"ID": "31107",
"label": "Label2",
"col": "col2"
},
{
"ID": "31109",
"label": "Label3",
"col": "col1"
 }, 
 {
"ID": "34567",
"col": "col2",
"label": "Label4"
},
 {
"ID": "21456",
"col": "col1",
"label": "Label5"
},
{
"ID": "22345",
"col": "col2",
"label": "Label6"
}
]
```

My requirement is very simple, if "col" attribute in my Json file equal "col1" then put the item in the first column of my table, else if it is equal to "col2" then put it in the second column. Is it possible to do this in XML ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have difficulties to understand the issue.
You say that only one cell is displayed by row.
If you then condense the items and delete all empty cells, won't all visible cells be in the first column?
Maybe it helps if you please post your updated view file, where you used the visible attribute of the tile tag and
a screenshot of the current look of your table?

Answer (score 0):

As much as I understand the question - [Expression binding](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw75/helpdata/en/5c/ff8d1c3fb84c5db7a00f2daca125af/content.htm) could help you.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Martin, You can try Expression binding on the "visible" property of the StandardTile.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used the visible attribute of the tile tag, but when I did this,  only one cell is displayed by row.
Have you any idea how to condense the items in order to delete all empty cells ?
Thanks in advance .....